# Combining UILabel declarations on one line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uikit

Why does Xcode not allow this:

```
UILabel*redlabel,greenlable,bluelabel;
```

But likes this:

```
UILabel*redlabel;
UILabel*greenlabel;
UILabel*bluelabel;
```

You can do this with other classes so why not UILabel? It gives an error "interface type cannot be statically allocated".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will work:

```
UILabel *redlabel, *greenlable, *bluelabel;
```

Answer (score 7):

By writing this : `UILabel *redlabel, greenlable, bluelabel;` you simply declare a pointer to `UILabel` and two `UILabel`s, not pointers.

It is equivalent to write :

```
UILabel *redlabel;
UILabel greenlabel;
UILabel bluelabel;
```

Try this instead, you need all three to be pointers :

```
UILabel *redlabel, *greenlable, *bluelabel;
```

Comment: +1, also, Take a look at pointer declaration syntax here: http://boredzo.org/pointers/

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
UILabel *redlabel,*greenlable,*bluelabel;
```